# How to change the content of the Span using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<span class="stbuttontext" st_page="home">ShareThis</span>
```

I want to change "Share This" to "Share",

please let me know the solution.

thanksl,

Comment: Remember to accept an answer by clicking a checkmark.

Comment: @ChristopherAltman and upvote it (at will).

Answer (score 121):

You can do with either:

```
$('.stbuttontext').text('Share');
```

for **textual** content or

```
$('.stbuttontext').html('Share');
```

for **html** contents.

In your case however, the first statement should be fine :)

Answer (score 23):

This is my way of thinking about when to use .html() vs. .text().

**Use .html() when you want to add styling with html tags to the text you are replacing, like:**

```
$('.stbuttontext').html('<strong>Share</strong>');
```

This is ofter useful when you are displaying an error message because you may want to add a class to change the color of the text.

```
$('#error').html('<span class="errortext red"><strong>Error:</strong> <em>Fix your email address</em></span>');`
```

**Use .text() when you simply want to change the text**.

So if you did the above example with .text:

`$('#error').text('<span class="errortext red"><strong>Error:</strong> <em>Fix your email address</em></span>');`

The text the user will see on the web page is (without the spaces in the tags, I could not figure out how to get it to work with this markdown editor).

< span class="errortext red">< strong>Error: < em>Fix your email address< /em>< /span>

and that text is not red, or have bold or italic text.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> $('.stbuttontext').html('Share');
> ```

Comment: You should really get in the habit of using `.text('Share')` when you aren't inserting HTML content.

Comment: @TM: why? isn't `html` faster? also `Share` *is* html content.

Comment: hey i also want to to do that but when i refresh the page the original content is coming. can i change that ?

Answer (score 3):

`$('.stbuttontext').html('Share');`

Will change the text of all spans with the class stbuttontext.