# Getting the name/ID of a field to dynamically add a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, dom

I am trying to add a hyperlink to this label::

[image]

I would like to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622293/117700) answer.

```
$('.fieldid').html('hyperlink');
```

However, I am unable to get the 'fieldid'

Here's what I see in the IE debugger:

[image]

Here's a full-sized [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/yEyjZrjFuZT).

I've asked a very related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660031/upgrading-javascript-that-adds-a-link-to-a-field) previously; however, in this question specifically I would like to know **how does one identify the ID of this field/label?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get the id of the element you highlighted in the inspector.  That would be the string after `id=` in the highlighted tag; or "salestagecode_c" to be specific.

To select that element using jQuery, you would use

```
$('#salestagecode_c')
```

Comment: thank you! whats the difference between that and $('.salesstagecode_c') .... hash vs. period? whats the diff?

Comment: jQuery selectors extend the syntax for CSS selectors.  I would highly recommend learning CSS before jQuery.

A hash selects an id while a period selects a class

Comment: what would i do if i wanted to change the html of that control? would i just say $('#salestagecode_c').html('myhtml...') ?

Comment: `.html` changes the inner html of the element, not the element itself.  If you want to change the element itself, you should use `.attr` to change specific attributes of the element.

Comment: having a difficult time finding a list of all available attributes

Comment: got it! $("#myLink_33").attr("href", "javascript:toggleMe(0);");

Comment: nice.  I would also recommend `$('#myLink_33').click(function () {toggleMe(0);});` and to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Reference for available attributes.

Comment: i did this $("#salesstagecode_c").attr("href", "javascript:toggleMe(0);");   however nothing changed. i then set the whole thing to a variable ..... var a = $("#salesstagecode_c").attr("href", "javascript:toggleMe(0);");  and i saw that "a" was indeed the correct object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67781/discussion-between-yuck-and-twinlakes).